# How can I extract a block of text based on the same information in unix

Tags: unix

Let's assume that I have a big file with the following pattern:

```
======start=========
id:xxxxxxxxx
.............
.............
======end===========
======start=========
id:xxxxxxxxx
............
............
======end===========
```

how can I extract those text blocks based on the entered id?.

Comment: best to show your required output in the body of your Q. Otherwise we have to guess if you want the start/end tags as well. (You're not really doing XML are you? You'll be sorry! ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try to `grep` with something like this:

```
$ grep id -A2 file.txt
```

It will return based on your example only the text between `==start==` and `==end==`

```
id:xxxxxxxxx
.............
.............
--
id:xxxxxxxxx
............
............
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm a PHP user mainly, this is PHP version:

save this as bigparser.php

```
<?php
if(empty($argv[2])){
    die('run as '.$argv[0].' bigfile.txt my-section-id');
}
$filename = $argv[1];
$section = $argv[2];

$handle = fopen($filename, "r") or die("Couldn't get file");
$printBuffer = false;

if ($handle) {
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $buffer = fgets($handle, 4096);
    if($printBuffer===true){
            if(trim($buffer)=="======end==========="){
                    die();
            }
            echo $buffer;
    } elseif(trim($buffer)=='id:'.$section){
       $printBuffer=true;
       continue;
    } 
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

and run as:

`php bigparser.php myfilename.txt abcdefg`

where `abcdefg` is of course `id:abcdefg`

Hope that helps.